# Wordpress Failed to Login (DB Error)

Tags: database, wp-login-form

is there anyone experience how to fix DB Error on WordPress (switch back to default theme and reset all plugins from FTP) but still cannot login). This is the erro I got:

```
WordPress database error: [Got error -1 from storage engine]
UPDATE `cm_options` SET `option_value` = '1436261132.2179160118103027343750' WHERE `option_name` = '_transient_doing_cron'
```

When click the login in wp form is nothing happened.

Thanks,

Comment: if you have access to database check your `cm_users` table and make sure your username is correct. There has been a lot of news about username being changed by something.

Comment: Hi, yes the username is correct. Got error -1 I think the error came from storage engine failure. Do you now how to fix this?

Comment: Yes sometimes i face the kind of error because of character set but that is mysql error. You are facing WordPress storage engine error which usually occurs with database is not up to date with WordPress version. Also the chance of this happens very low. Did you update the version of wp recently?

Comment: Nope, I did not update the wordpress version. Is suddenly happened. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error -1 is fairly broad, but has a few common causes:

1. A full disk
2. Memory or resource issues on the server (check mysql logs)
3. Database Corruption (run checks on the database tables)

If the issue winds up being database corruption, you will want to follow the repair procedures for the storage engine used for the corrupted tables. If all else fails, roll to a backup.